# Parsing JSon Data using java (google-gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

Trying to learn how to use JSON and parse the json data.i am using `google-gson` API to parse my json data.

i am getting my JSON data in the following format

```
{"guid":{"uri":"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid","value":"123456789"}}
```

and here is my parsing code using `google-gson`

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
MyGuid myGuid=new MyGuid();
myGuid=gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), MyGuid.class);

public class MyGuid {

public MyGuid() {

}

private String value;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

but i am getting the value of guid as null.
I know i am doing wrong but being new to JSON format is what making me more confused.

Any help in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or *at least* the actual code of your `MyGuid` class (except getters/setters).

Comment: Before you worry about mixing in your domain classes etc., hard code the JSON as a string, parse that with Gson, get that working, and then worry about the more complicated case of getting JSON from a response object, hooking it up to your class, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data structures should reflect the data you are trying to de-serialize.

For example, you could use something of this form:

```
public class Data {
  private Map<String, String> guid;

  public Map<String, String> getGuid() {
    return guid;
  }

  public void setGuid(Map<String, String> guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json =
        "{\"guid\":{" + "\"uri\":\"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid\","
            + "\"value\":\"123456789\"}}";
    Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);
    System.out.println(data.getGuid()
        .get("uri"));
  }
}
```

The `guid` property of the JSON is mapped to the `guid` property of the `Data` type. The properties of that object are placed in a `Map` as strings.